# Storing a single list of references to elements in several other lists in python

Tags: python

I have several lists, let's say they look like:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And I want to have a list or similarly iterable data structure which stores all the elements in both a and b:

```
c = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

changing any of these elements changes the corresponding element in the original list.

```
c[0] = 10
a
[10, 1, 2]
```

Most resources I've found are concerned with doing the opposite - creating list copies with distinct IDs for the elements. Is there a simple solution?

EDIT - Ilja Everilä suggested itertools.chain which works nicely. Although it doesn't support mutation, I can use it to build new lists which fits my use case.

Comment: you could do `c = a + b`

Comment: tried that - doesn't work as desired. changing c will not change the a and b lists

Comment: Use a [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) when you need to iterate over the lists in sequence. It will not support subscriptions or mutating, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
class IndirectList():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.array = list()

        for subarray in range(len(args)):
            for element in range(len(args[subarray])):
                self.array.append((args[subarray], element))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.array)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in range(len(self.array)):
            raise IndexError
        return (self.array[key][0])[self.array[key][1]]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key not in range(len(self.array)):
            raise IndexError
        (self.array[key][0])[self.array[key][1]] = value
```

**USAGE**

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c = IndirectList(a, b)
>>> c
<__main__.IndirectList object at 0x10187d9b0>
>>> list(c)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> c[4]
4
>>> c[4] = 13
>>> list(c)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 13, 5, 6]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2]
>>> b
[3, 13, 5, 6]
>>> a[1] = -42
>>> a
[0, -42, 2]
>>> b
[3, 13, 5, 6]
>>> list(c)
[0, -42, 2, 3, 13, 5, 6]
```

This class needs extending and optimizing but the basic idea is there.